# Finding the volume of the region described by $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$ and $|y|\le x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

As the title says, how do I find the volume of this region in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

My attempt:
What we have are two identical cylinders which intersect the unit sphere, meet at the origin and each have diameter 1. As a result we can take the octant where $x,y,z >0$ and multiply the resulting volume by 8.

How should i go about doing the actual integration? Is it best to use polar co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I would use polar coordinates and do the solid part and the hole separately. The solid part is straightforward:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dz\,r\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}2\int_0^1(1-r^2)^{\frac12}r\,dr=\left.\frac{\pi}2\left(-\frac13\right)(1-r^2)^{\frac32}\right|_0^1=\frac{\pi}6$$
In agreement with the classical mensuration formula. After that little warm-up, we move on to the hole. The condition is $-x^2-y^2\le y\le x^2+y^2$. Interruption...

**EDIT**: Got my freedom back temporarily. As I was saying, the left half of the inequality above after completing the square reads $\frac14\le x^2+\left(y+\frac12\right)^2$, which is a cylindrical hole of radius $\frac12$ centered on the line $y=-\frac12$, and the right half reads $\frac14\le x^2+\left(y-\frac12\right)^2$, and that is another hole, same radius, centered on $y=\frac12$. This is the hole that impacts the first octant, and in cylindrical coordinates may be parameterized as $r=\sin\theta$, $0\le\theta\le\pi$. The part of the hole that cuts through the first octant has volume
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{\sin\theta}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dz\,r\,dr\,d\theta&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{\sin\theta}r\sqrt{1-r^2}\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left.-\frac13(1-r^2)^{\frac32}\right|_0^{\sin\theta}d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(-\frac13\cos^3\theta+\frac13\right)d\theta\\&=\frac13\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(1-\cos\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac13\left[\theta-\sin\theta+\frac13\sin^3\theta\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\\
&=\frac13\left(\frac{\pi}2-1+\frac13\right)=\frac{\pi}6-\frac29\end{align}$$
Is that the right size for the holes? Two cylinders of radius $\frac12$, average height about $\sqrt3$ adds up to about $2\sqrt3\frac{\pi}4\approx2.721$ vs. the integrated size of $8\left(\frac{\pi}6-\frac29\right)\approx2.411$, so we are relatively confident in out results.

Now we can subtract the hole from solid sphere and multiply by $8$ to get
$$8\times\left(\frac{\pi}6-\left(\frac{\pi}6-\frac29\right)\right)=\frac{16}9$$
For the volume of the sphere remaining after we drilled the $2$ holes out.

Comment: I don't quite understand the distinction between the hole and the solid. What is the first part the volume of? So the volume of the whole is just $\frac{4\pi}{3} - \frac{16}{9}$?

Comment: Sorry, work called suddenly and I had to abort. Pizza and hot chocolate and perhaps a little more clarity in my presentation.